# Recursive function returns None

Tags: python, recursion

I am using recursive function to get file size in each directory, but getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'. However I checked all files inside all subdir, I don't see any file returning None Type:

```
import os
def disk_usage(path):
    """
    this function resursiverly check file size in each diretory and return size of 
    path/directory
    provided.
    """
    total = os.path.getsize(path)
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        for file in os.listdir(path):
            subdir = os.path.join(path, file)
            print(subdir)
            total +=disk_usage(subdir)
    print ("{} for path {}".format(total, path))
path = "/home/akjha/Documents/Aashutosh_cfengine/"
disk_usage(path)
```

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946790/recursive-function-on-sublist-returning-none https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60261962/recursive-function-return-none

Comment: In any other language you'd get a warning telling you you forgot a `return` statement, but python likes to pretend everything is alright and silently returns `None` when you forget to explicitly return a value.

Answer (score 3):

At the end of `disk_usage` you need to add

```
return total
```

otherwise without a `return` statement it will implicitly `return None` which will cause

```
total += disk_usage(subdir)
```

to add an `int` to `None`

Answer (score 2):

Your method `disk_usage()` doesn't *return* anything. In python, a method that doesn't explicitly return something will instead return `None` by default.

When you recursively call

```
total +=disk_usage(subdir)
```

`disk_usage(subdir)` returns `None`, which produces your error.

Solution: put

```
return total
```

at the end of the function, before de-indenting.